# How to access toolbar object of nestedlist view from another view's callback in sencha touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new in Sencha Touch, so I don't know it's full structure. So the question is a little stupid, i guess :)

I have a view it is a nestedlist object. I have created a toolar object inside my nestedlist. Now I want to manipulate this toolbar from another view's callback. How can I access my toolbar object located in nestedlist view from event callback from another view object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that little information on your structure (are you using the MVC pattern? No example code given) I can only say that you can definitely achieve this with **[Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)**

Lets say you added a custom property to your toolbar named `ident='myToolbar'` then you can access this toolbar (precisely said any toolbar with that custom property) by calling

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[ident=myToolbar]')[0]
```

The result will be always a array but in this example we accept only one result, that is why I added `[0]`

For further information refer to the API. **[Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)** is mighty if you know how to use it.

Comment: @Tracker I noticed an typo in the query example. Now it should work a expected.

Answer (score 0):

First give your toolbar an `id`, for example `myToolbar`. Then, in your callback, you can do something like this

```
var toolbar = Ext.getCmp('myToolbar');
```

to get your toolbar object. Next you can manipulate the toolbar using the toolbar variable, for example change the title:

```
toolbar.setTitle('New Title');
```

More info about getCmp() [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp).

More info about the toolbar [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Toolbar) (Check the toolbar's methods to manipulate it).

Comment: This is bad especially for one who is just starting Sencha Touch or ExtJS. It can lead to duplicate id's which lead to various errors.